# Описание типа данных  TGlobalDLLData

Tags: delphi

Помогите разобраться с типом данных `^TGlobalDLLData`, что означает в данной записи?

```
type
  PGlobalDLLData = ^TGlobalDLLData;
  TGlobalDLLData = packed record
    WndHook: HWND;
    Wnd: HWND;
  end;
```

Comment: @Naruto, Старайтесь грамотно оформлять вопрос, выделять код, расставлять знаки препинания. Качественное показывает ваш уровень проф-пригодности, а также ускоряет получение ответа.

Answer (score 1):

1. TGlobalDLLData - упакованная запись, содержащая два поля.
2. PGlobalDLLData - указатель на вышеупомянутую запись.